# The ajax Status in Developement tools is 200, but why is it falling into error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="show_allMember.do",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String memberList(Model mav)
{
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> members = aService.getMemberList();
    mav.addAttribute("mList", members);
    return "" + mav ;
}
```

view.jsp

```
function show_allMember()
{
    $('.member_management_area').css('display','block');
    $('.member_management').css('color','#fe4978');

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/rachelivf/show_allMember.do',
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert('success');
            $.each(response.mList, function(index, value)
            {

            });
       },
       error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError)
       {
           alert('error');
           if(xhr.status == 404)
         {
               alert(thrownError);
         }
       }
     });
}
```

When you run the project, the status is 200 times.

On the Network tab, values ​​are also displayed in the header and in the preview.

However, it falls into error, not success..

As far as I know, the data types do not match. So  falling into error .

Am I right? What should I do if I'm right?

Comment: You will get this behaviour if the request works, but the format of the response does not match what you have told jQuery to expect. In your case this means that the response isn't valid JSON. Check the network tab of the console to see exactly what is being sent back

Comment: You expect json data in client side (e.g in ajax `dataType:'JSON',`) but you didn't send any json data from server.

Comment: Add a null check for your members object.... Returning 200 only means the network request for successful, not the backend or your java code.

Comment: @WeareBorg Is it possible to chat 1: 1?

Comment: I am in my lunch break. I will chat in 30 with u.

Comment: ok, I wait you @WeareBorg

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151365/jquery-for-user

Comment: check ur chat man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add a null check in your controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value="show_allMember.do",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String memberList(Model mav)
{
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> members = aService.getMemberList();
     if(members!=null){
    mav.addAttribute("mList", members);
    return "" + mav ;
    }else{
       return "denied.jsp";
    }
}
```

Handle this JSP code in your jquery code.